# Winforms, redrawing at same framerate as monitor

Tags: winforms, game-development, frame-rate

I'm trying to render my game to the winform at same framerate as the monitor runs, not more not less, but it seems impossible. Timers are simply not precise or consistent enough, is there someway i can get an event from some windows dll corrosponding to the framerate of the monitor?

Or maybe from within the form class itself, since windows renders its own desktop and forms corrosponding to the monitor framerate without any syncing isssues it must have a timing or reading mechanism for it somewhere

Comment: Well, I think you're finding out that WinForms is not a gaming platform.

Comment: What else can i use then? Opengl and DX games use winforms as well

Comment: Guessing you should look at Unity.